# Accessing parent class objects & variables through $this?

Tags: php, class, parent, extends

I have one main class "main", which I use to store the configuration and a few objects. However, I am unable to access the objects & variables in a class which extends main, through `$this`.

Here is some of my main class:

```
<?php
class main{
    // the configuration vars
    public $config = array();
    // the current user variables
    public $uid; // contains the user ID
    public $gid; // contains the group ID
    // database variables
    public $DB; // contains the connection
    public $query_id; // contains the query ID
    public $query_count; // how many queries have there been?
    // cache variables
    public $cache;
    // start up functions
    public function startup(){
        // first, set up the caching
        if(function_exists('memcache_connect') AND $this->config['use_memcache'] == true){
            // start up memcache
            require_once('memcache.class.php');
            $this->cache = Cache::getInstance();
        }
        // now, set up the DB
        $this->connectToDatabase();
        // now, set up the user session
        $this->setUserSession();
        // are we logged in? If so, update our location
        if($this->uid > 0){
            // update location
            $this->updateUserSession();
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of another class

```
<?php
class user extends main{
        public function viewProfile($uid){
                exit($this->config['session_prefix']); // displays nothing
                if($this->cache->exists('key')){ // fails
```

The $config value is correctly set up, and I can read it within `main` but not any sub class.
The $cache->exists object just results in `Call to a member function exists() on a non-object`.

On index.php, the classes are loaded and set up. The Main class is setup first, and the startup function is called. The configuration array is passed before startup is called.

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your array is correctly set up.

This simple test works for me:

```
<?
class main {
    public $test = "Woot";
}

class test extends main {
    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->test;
    }
}

$t = new test();
```

Just for testing purposes, add a variable $test like in my example to the class main and try to echo it in the user constructor.

I would check if your cache is really set up correctly.
Probably the error is in this if statement:

```
if(function_exists('memcache_connect') AND $this->config['use_memcache'] == true){
```

One of these two conditions isn't met, so your $cache variable won't get initialized.

Comment: The if function is to blame for the $cache not working. I tried a $test value, and it returned the value correctly. But $config is blank, and var_dump of `$this->config` just gives an empty array. I know it is not empty, as the connectToDatabase() function works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parent::` to referance variables in the parent class.

```
parent::cache->exists('key')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access parent class's attributes by $this->attribute, so the problem should be that you are not calling the constructor of the parent...

Like this code is perfectly working:

```
    <?php
    class foo {
        public $x="aa";

    }
    class bar extends foo {
        public function barbar()
        {
              echo $this->x;
        }
    }
    $b = new bar;
    $b->barbar(); 
    ?>
```

Though you can also access parent class properties by Parent::attr()

Comment: I set up a test variable in the main class, and I can access it fine in user, but the $config array is still blank. I know it is not blank, as connectToDatabase() works.